# PostgreSQL 13: create empty copy of database

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I have a AWS RDS PostgreSQL 13 server with some databases. I have to create an empty copy of one database (empty means schema (tables, views, functions) + security (users, roles)).

Is `pg_dump -s` what I am looking for?

Thanks!

Comment: Should have asked whether you want to create the new database on the existing cluster or a new one?

Comment: on existing cluser (server) for now, however request to create replica on new cluster will come soon

Comment: If you are doing it on existing cluster then it would be better to use @BryanST25's answer, otherwise you will need to need to rename references to the database in the dump files.

Comment: yeah got it, but @Bryan's answer will also include data, wont it?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pg_dump -d db_name -s`. You will also need to do `pg_dumpall -g` to get the global data e.g. roles. This will get all global data for the Postgres cluster, so you may have more then you need for the particular database.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres allows the use of any existing database on the server as a template when creating a new database. I'm not sure whether pgAdmin gives you the option on the create database dialog but you should be able to execute the following in a query window if it doesn't:

```
CREATE DATABASE newdb WITH TEMPLATE originaldb OWNER dbuser;
```

Still, you may get:

```
ERROR:  source database "originaldb" is being accessed by other users
```

To disconnect all other users from the database, you can use this query:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'originaldb' AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```